# Date Format Excel VBA

Tags: excel, date, vba

What I am trying to do is format specific columns as date.
However problem arises when I have two types of format in the same column,
for example, just the years (2010) in general format and a full date in date format. When I format the whole column as date, some just displays as random year like 1905. Is there a way to fix this so I can see all of the values?

When I format them as date, then the years that were formatted as general would change to some weird date whereas when I format them as general, full date converts to a random number.

```
01/01/1962
01/01/1966
01/01/1956
  1964
01/01/1943
01/01/1943
01/01/1964
  1964
01/01/1972
01/01/1948
01/01/1961
01/01/1953
01/01/1961
01/01/1963
01/01/1963
01/01/1973
  1960
01/01/1956
01/01/1940
  1958
1958
1955
01/01/1948
01/01/1948
01/01/1970
  1959
  1964
01/01/1975
  1966
```

This becomes

```
22647
24108
20455
1964
15707
15707
19
23377
1964
26299
17533
22282
19360
22282
23012
23012
26665
1960
20455
14611
1958
1958
1955
17533
17533
25569
1959
1964
27395
1966
```

And the latter column is in 'Text' format. I dont know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Format the column as Text in order to be able to see both types of formats